# Unwind Segue with programmatically created Labels

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added label programmatically in one controller view. When user double clicks on label I want to do UnWind Segue so how can i connect my programmatically created Label to "Exit" as done with Buttons not created programmatically?

I know tapGestureRecognizer can be useful but I have only issue with connecting UIlabel to Exit.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Segues need to be connected in the storyboard (there's a reason the class name is UIStoryboardSegue). However, you can connect the controller itself to the exit icon in the storyboard, then call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: in code in response to double clicking on the label.

Comment: I want to send the value of UILabel to another controller after tapping on Label that is created programmatically

Comment: @user3763512, yeah, so do you have a question?

Comment: If i am doing segue it is only navigating to another view controller but not displaying the text of label in textview. Do I have to call them string in viewdidLoad of 2nd View? I have tried this too but it isn't displaying the text.

Comment: @user3763512, you pass the string you want to show to the unwind segue method, and then set the text of your label inside that method also (not in viewDidLoad which won't be called again anyway).